# ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.imovirtual.com/comprar/apartamento/lisboa/> (referer: None)

Tags: python, css, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a web crawler (in python, using scrapy) that extracts information from an ad, extract what is on the main page and enter the sub page of the same ad and extract the remaining information, but is giving this error when I run the code. Any suggestion?

```
import scrapy

class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "imo"
start_urls = ['https://www.imovirtual.com/comprar/apartamento/lisboa/']

def parse(self,response):
    for Property in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
        youritem = {
        'preco':Property.css('span.offer-item title::text').extract_first(),
        'autor':Property.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
        'data':Property.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
        'data_2':Property.css('li.offer-item-price-perm::text').extract()
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage)

#            next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
#            if next_page is not None:
#                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
#                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_subpage(self,youritem):
    for i in response.css('header[class=offer-item-header] a::attr(href)'):
        youritem = {
        'info': i.css('ul.main-list::text').extract(),
        }
        yield youritem
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to change to make it run:

You have to set `subpage_link` (It does not seem to be defined)

Request callbacks have only one parameter which is (Scrapy response) so you 
should replace `parse_subpage(self,youritem)` by `parse_subpage(self, reponse)`

To send your item with the Request you'd better use Request meta parameter which allows you to transfer data from one scrapy response to another. If you replace `scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage)` by `scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage, meta={'item': youritem})` you will have access to `youritem` when scrapy will call `parse_subpage` by doing `response.meta.get('item')`

This should work.

```
def parse(self,response):
    for Property in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
        youritem = {
        'preco':Property.css('span.offer-item title::text').extract_first(),
        'autor':Property.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
        'data':Property.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
        'data_2':Property.css('li.offer-item-price-perm::text').extract()
        }
        subpage_link = ...... 
        yield scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage,
                             meta={'item': youritem})

#            next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
#            if next_page is not None:
#                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
#                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_subpage(self, response):
    for i in response.css('header[class=offer-item-header] a::attr(href)'):
        youritem = response.meta.get('item')
        youritem['info'] = i.css('ul.main-list::text').extract()
        yield youritem
```

Comment: Thank you!
in the subpage_link I put i.css ('header [class = offer-item-header] a :: attr (href)') but the same error continued to appear and the new error appeared: "TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got SelectorList ". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `i` in `i.css ('header [class = offer-item-header] a :: attr (href)')` you mean the `i` in `parse_subpage`? 
It's probably because you've forgotten to add `.extract_first()` to `i.css ('header [class = offer-item-header] a :: attr (href)')`, because `response.css()` returns `SelectorList` whereas `response.css().extract_first()` returns the content of the first selector (which is in your case the `href`) that's why you have this error `TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got SelectorList`

Comment: I have already corrected this error and now it does not appear to me ... but my crawler is not collecting information ... any suggestions?

Comment: Did you configure `FEED_URI` ? You can define it like by setting this spider attribut custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'path where you want to store data'
    }
But there is another problem I think with `parse_subpage` because `i`is a defined as a `href` so i don't think it will have `ul`.

Comment: I already solved the problem, thanks for the help :)
I just have an issue .. when I do for example this command: "j.css ('ul.dotted-list, li.h4 :: text'). extract ()", I wanted to appear only the information that it It contains but it appears that it is written there and the information. What can I do to just get the information?

Comment: Look there I've wrote the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957522/info-crawled-0-pages-at-0-pages-min-scraped-0-items-at-0-items-min/50965873#50965873