# INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, css, scrapy, web-crawler

I just began to learn Python and Scrapy.
My first project is to crawl information on a website containing web security information. But when I run that using cmd, it says that "Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)" and nothing seems to come out. I'd be grateful if someone kind could solve my problem.

My code:

```
import scrapy

class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "imo"
allowed_domains = ["imovirtual.com"]
start_urls = ["https://www.imovirtual.com/arrendar/apartamento/lisboa/"]

def parse(self,response):
    subpage_links = []
    for i in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
        youritem = {
        'preco':i.css('span.offer-item title::text').extract_first(),
        'autor':i.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
        'data':i.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
        'data_2':i.css('li.offer-item-price-perm::text').extract()
        }
        subpage_link = i.css('header[class=offer-item-header] a::attr(href)').extract()
        subpage_links.extend(subpage_link)

        for subpage_link in subpage_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage, meta={'item':youritem})

def parse_subpage(self,response):
    for j in response.css('header[class=offer-item-header] a::attr(href)'):
        youritem = response.meta.get('item')
        youritem['info'] = j.css(' ul.dotted-list, li.h4::text').extract()
        yield youritem
```

Comment: Where are you using `start_urls`?

Comment: probably nowhere ... where should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to correct to make it work:

- You need to define FEED_URI setting with the path you want to store the result
- You need to use `response` in `parse_subpage` because the logic is the following`: scrapy downloads "https://www.imovirtual.com/arrendar/apartamento/lisboa/" and gives the response to`parse`, you extract ads url and you ask scrapy to download each pages and give the downloaded pages to`parse_subpage`. So`response`in`parse_subpage` corresponds to this https://www.imovirtual.com/anuncio/t0-totalmente-remodelado-localizacao-excelente-IDGBAY.html#913474cdaa for example

This should work:

```
import scrapy


class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imo"
    allowed_domains = ["imovirtual.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.imovirtual.com/arrendar/apartamento/lisboa/"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': './output.json'
    }
    def parse(self,response):
        subpage_links = []
        for i in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
            youritem = {
            'preco':i.css('span.offer-item title::text').extract_first(),
            'autor':i.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
            'data':i.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
            'data_2':i.css('li.offer-item-price-perm::text').extract()
            }
            subpage_link = i.css('header[class=offer-item-header] a::attr(href)').extract()
            subpage_links.extend(subpage_link)

            for subpage_link in subpage_links:
                yield scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage, meta={'item':youritem})

    def parse_subpage(self,response):
        youritem = response.meta.get('item')
        youritem['info'] = response.css(' ul.dotted-list, li.h4::text').extract()
        yield youritem
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
But I still have the problem of not just getting the information from this line of code: "response.css ('ul.dotted-list, li.h4 :: text'). Extract ()". What prints from this line is the ul.dotted-list <li> information </ li> and I wanted it to appear just the information ... how do I do this?
And another question, if I want to insert more information to extract from the subpage just add several more to that same correct code?

Comment: So you should replace it by `response.css(' ul.dotted-list li::text').extract()`.
Yes if you want to get more infomartion you can just put it in `youritem`
e.g `youritem['title']=response.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()`

Comment: Thanks for you help :)
Can you help me with one more thing? I need the database to always be updated and this happens because the crawlers are always updating, how do I synchronize the crawlers? any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronize the crawlers ? If I understand well, you want that the data in your data is still up-to-date, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to be always up-to-date without constantly scraping. But I think that a good practice would be to scrape everyday even though you would be up to date at least every day.